# VB + SQL SUM with condition

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

i'm trying to get this code to work.

```
  SELECT InputDate       
        ,Number       
        ,Name       
        ,Sector       
        ,YukyuDate       
        ,YukyuIn       
        ,YukyuOut       
        ,ISNULL(SUM(YukyuIn), 0)-ISNULL(SUM(YukyuOut), 0)As YukyuLeft
        ,Reason  
    FROM TYukyu 
   WHERE Number = '0011683963'
GROUP BY Number
ORDER BY InputDate
```

i already tried

```
SUM(YukyuIn-YukyuOut) As YukyuLeft
SUM(YukyuIn)-SUM(YukyuOut) As YukyuLeft
```

My sql have this colums

```sql
    InputDate   |Number|Name |Sector |YukyuDate |YukyuIn|YukyuOut|Reason
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-26 11:50|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|   10  |        |Test1
2016-06-26 11:51|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |Test2
2016-06-26 11:52|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |Test3
2016-06-26 11:53|  2   |User2|Sector1|2016-06-26|   10  |    0   |Test4
2016-06-26 11:54|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |Test5
2016-06-26 11:55|  3   |User3|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |Test6
```

i want this results to show in datagridview

```html
    InputDate   |Number|Name |Sector |YukyuDate |YukyuIn|YukyuOut|YukyuLeft|Reason
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-26 11:50|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|   10  |        |  10     |Test1
2016-06-26 11:51|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |   9     |Test2
2016-06-26 11:52|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |   8     |Test3
2016-06-26 11:54|  1   |User1|Sector1|2016-06-26|       |    1   |   7     |Test5
```

Comment: It would help if you described the error you received, if there is an error.  Also, `Left` is a SQL keyword, try: `SUM(YukyuIn)-SUM(YukyuOut) As [Left]`

Comment: tried  as SUM(YukyuIn)-SUM(YukyuOut) As YukyuLeft and still get the error  Column 'TYukyu.InputDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Your selects must be in the group by clause. The reason is because of the group by is for aggregate. Just remove the group by since your where clause is handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      SELECT InputDate       
                ,Number       
                ,Name       
                ,Sector       
                ,YukyuDate       
                ,YukyuIn       
                ,YukyuOut       
                ,SUM(isnull(YukyuIn,0)-isnull(YukyuOut,0)) 
over (partition by number order by InputDate) as YukyuLeft
                ,Reason  
            FROM TYukyu 
           WHERE Number = '0011683963'
        ORDER BY InputDate


    '
```

Comment: thank you very much worked perfect. i search a lot on google, and get no solution, then i tried here and in minutes get this answer.